# Show that all real number can be approximated by the difference between square root of two different integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $x \in \mathbb R$, show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $a,b \in \mathbb Z$ such that:
$$
\left|x - \left(\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}\right)\right| < \epsilon
$$

Not sure how to approach this, how do you show the difference between square roots of integers can be arbitrary.

any hints would be helpful!

Comment: Sorry, but why do you want to solve a problem even though you have no idea how to approach it? What is the origin of the problem, what is your motivation, what are problems you *could* solve?

Comment: As a way to get started:  what density theorems do you know?  Start with one of the standard results, try to adapt it to this question;

Comment: @ProfessorVector Thanks for the comment, It's an exercise for an elementary number theory course, and my motivation is to be able to solve the problem. I certainly don't know of any applications of this fact as my knowledge is number theory is limited, any insight into the problem or the application would be appreciated.

Comment: @lulu This is an exercise for an elementary number theory course, we have not learned of any density theorems. (I searched up density theorems and I think those are related to algebraic number theory?)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to approach this. Here's one of them:

**Hint:** For any integers $n, k$, show that there exists integers $a, b$ such that

$$ \frac{k}{2^n } < \sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b} < \frac{k+1}{2^n}. $$

**Corollary:** Given any $x$, we can first approximate it by $ \frac{k}{2^n}$, then by $ \sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}$.

Fill in the gaps as needed. If you're stuck, write out your working and thought process to demonstrate where you're at.

---

Here's another approach.

**Hint:** For $ x \geq 0$, let $ b_n = n^2$ and $ a_n = \lceil  (n+x)^2 \rceil $. Show that

$$ |x - ( \sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{b_n} )| < \frac{1}{ n}. $$

(We could get a tighter bound, but this is all that we need.)

Comment: Thanks Calvin, the second approach it's easy to understand. I'm trying to work through the problem with the first approach, is there a reason you specifically choose the fraction $\frac{k}{2^n}$ that makes the proof easier? or would it essentially be the same if say you use $\frac{k}{n}$ and $\frac{k + 1}{n}$ as the lower and upper bound of $\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}$.

Comment: @link No, any bounds that tend to 0 will do. It was just the first that came to mind. The main difference is that the first is merely existence, while the second explicitly finds values.